# How does python achieve the following data format conversion?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to achieve a function that deals with the following data：'d' and generate 'L'. How to achieve?

```
def func(**d):
   'do something'
    return [....]
```

source:

```
   d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4, 5]}
```

or

```
   d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4, 5], 'd': [6, 7]}
```

---

TO:

```
  L=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
   {'a':1,'b':2,'c':4},
   {'a':1,'b':2,'c':5}]
```

or

```
  L=[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 7},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 7},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 7}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2,' c': [3, 4, 5]}

temp_d = d
L = []
for key in temp_d:
  item = {} 
  for key in temp_d:
      if isinstance(temp_d[key], list):
        item[key]  = temp_d[key].pop(0)
      else:
        item[key]  = temp_d[key] 
  L.append(item)
```

Basically, what i am doing here is:

- I create a copy of the dictionary 'd' named 'temp_d';
- I go through every key in the 'temp_d ' dictionary, and create an empty one;
- I loop again through all the keys in the 'd' dictionary, and basically I verify if the value of the current key of the loop is a list, if it is, I add the key to the dictionary 'item' with the first value of the list, with the function pop(index) (this function removes an element from a list and returns it). If the value of the current key isn't a list, it just adds the key to the dict with the value.
- After filling the dictionary 'item', I append it to 'L'.

Example in this case:

```
first key ('a'):
  item = {}

  first key of second loop ('a'):
     is the value of 'a' a list?
     no. adds the value.
  new item{'a': 1}

  second key of second loop ('b'):
     is the value of 'b' a list?
     no. adds the value.
  new item{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

  third key of second loop ('c'):
     is the value of 'c' a list?
     yes. adds the first element of the list, removing it from the list
     (the list was [3, 4, 5], now is [4, 5])
  new item{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

  appends the item to L
  (the 'L' was [], now is [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}])
```

etc until the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with python 3:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4, 5]}
def f(**d):
    return [{**d, 'c': i} for i in d.pop('c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved as follows:

```
from itertools import cycle

def func(indict):
    dictlist = [dict(indict)] # make copy to not change original dict
    for key in indict: # loop keys to find lists
        if type(indict[key]) == list:
            listlength = len(indict[key])
            dictlist = listlength * dictlist # elements are not unique
            for dictindex, listelement in zip(range(len(dictlist)), cycle(indict[key])):
                dictlist[dictindex] = dict(dictlist[dictindex]) # uniquify
                dictlist[dictindex][key] = listelement # replace list by list element
    return dictlist
```

In the general case you can have multiple lists in your dict. My solution assumes you want to unroll all of these.

Looking at the details of the solution, it starts by adding a copy of your original dict to `dictlist` then it cycles the elements and whenever it finds a list, it multiplies the `dictlist` with the the length of the list found. This will ensure that `dictlist` contains the correct number of elements.

However, the elements will not be unique as they will be references to the same underlying dicts.

To fix this, the elements of the dict list are "uniquified" by looping the list and replacing every element with a copy of itself and the list in the original `indict` is replaced by each element of the list, cycling the different elements of `dictlist`.

I know my explanation is a bit messy. I'm sorry about that, but I find it hard to explain in a short and simple way.

Also, the order of the element in the list, is not identical to what you ask for in the question. Since the individual key-value pairs of the dict are not ordered, it is not possible to ensure which order the elements will be unrolled, which leads to the list order is also not ensured.